# angular oidc - error when calling signinRedirect

Tags: angular, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

Checking with the most awesome community too! I've posted my issue here - https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/910.

Can anyone help me, please? Kindly let me know if you need more information :pray

Comment: I commented there, just in case you don't know yet.
I recommend you to use this package: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: @RicardoFerreira Thank you for your help :) I figured out the issue. `client_id` was returned as `null` from my api and it took me a while to figure out the difference between `i` and `I`. Missing things like this makes me want to fire myself :D

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. But have a look in the package I shared also. Its good because is designed to be used in angular.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting. Will take a look. Thanks again :)